# How to create the leaflet map in angular formly

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-formly, angular-leaflet-directive

My requirement is to create the leaflet map in angular formly,but I am new to this formly

and I know how to use integrate the map with normal html in angular as below

**map.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
        const map = L.map('map').setView([51.509865,-0.118092], 10);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
    }
```

**map.component.html**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**map.component.css**

```
div{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

But,Now I have to place the leaflet map in angular formly, can anyone help me regarding this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom component of leaflet map and use it wherever in your project:

LeafletMapComponent.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="map" leaflet
        [leafletOptions]="Options"
        (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)" >
        </div>
</div>
```

LeafletMapComponent.css

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  }
```

LeafletMapcomponent.ts

```
 constructor() { }
  map;
  @Input() markers;
  @Output() LMarkerclicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() setPositon: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  Options = {
    layers: [
      tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
    ],
    zoom: 7,
    center: latLng(29.6060218, 52.5378041)
  };
 ngOnInit() {
  }
  onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map = map;
      map.invalidateSize();
      this.addMarker();
    }, 0);
    map.on('click', (e)=>{this.onMapClick(e)});
  }
addMarker() {
    this.markers.forEach((mapMarker) => {
      let m = L.marker([mapMarker.lat, mapMarker.lng], {
        draggable: true,
        icon: new L.DivIcon({
          className: 'my-div-icon',
          html: '<img class="my-div-image" src="' + mapMarker.icon +'" />'+
                '<label class="MarkerLabel">'+ mapMarker.label +'</label>'
      })
      }).addTo(this.map).bindPopup("<b>" + mapMarker.info + "</b><br>" + mapMarker.label).on('click', this.markerClick, this).on('dragend', this.markerDragend, this);
    });
  }
  markerClick(e) {
    this.LMarkerclicked.emit(e.latlng);
  }
  markerDragend(e){
   this.LMarkerclicked.emit(e.target._latlng);
  }
```

Then for using it :

```
<app-leaflet-map [markers]="markers" (LMarkerclicked)="onClickLMarker($event)" (setPositon)="onClickLMarker($event)"></app-leaflet-map>
```

and in your ts file:

```
markers: MapmarkerVm[] = [
  {
    lat: 29.60602,
    lng: 52.53780,
    label: '',
    draggable: true,
    icon: '../assets/images/marker-active.png',
    info: 'cityName'
  },
];
onClickLMarker(e) {
  this.addEditForm.controls["Latitude"].reset(e.lat);
  this.addEditForm.controls["Longtude"].reset(e.lng);
}



   export class MapmarkerVm {
            lat: number;
            lng: number;
            label?: string;
            draggable: boolean;
            icon:string;
            info:String;
    }
```