# How to integrate the leaflet map in angular

Tags: angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, angular-formly, angular-leaflet-directive

I  want to show the leaflet map in angular application
**As I have used the angular formly for application with tabs because In my application I have to create the dynamic forms**

In third tab I have to place leaflet map and remaining tabs  containing form fields So my problem is to create the map in the tab(used formly)

**.component.ts**

```
//Areas covered

export class ProcessComponent implements OnInit {

areascoveredForm = new FormGroup({});
areascoveredModel: any = {};
areasOptions: FormlyFormOptions = {};


  // Measure Details form
  measureDetailsForm = new FormGroup({});
  measureDetailsModel: any = {};
  measureDetailsOptions: FormlyFormOptions = {};

//In area coverd tab I need to placethe map

areacoveredFields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [

//need to place the map
]

**.component.html**

<mat-tab label="AREAS COVERED">Tab 1</mat-tab>
```

In normal I know How to place the map but in this angular formly tab format I am facing the issu

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? [How to create the leaflet map in angular formly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667646/how-to-create-the-leaflet-map-in-angular-formly)

Comment: Tried but facing the problem with including the custom component(leaflet component)in in existing component where ever I have used the formly and in module.ts Can you help me regarding this